# Can't run Second life firestorm viewer (32bit) in ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: 12.04, games, shared-library

I'm trying to install a *Second Life* client called *Phoenix Viewer*.

On the first attempt, I got a message about X errors. I searched the net all I could see to fix 32 bit apps and run them under 64 bit `Ubuntu` was shared libraries issues, so I installed all libraries that I found suggested in all articles but the error persists.

Can someone help or at least give me a hint on what to do?

This is my output (too long I know, but I thought I should include all info):

```
    deus@work:~/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720$ ./firestorm 
64-bit Linux detected.
Multi-arch support detected.
Running from /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720
./firestorm: line 98: ./etc/register_hopprotocol.sh: No such file or directory
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: llcommon/llerror.cpp(334) : (anonymous namespace)::LogControlFile::loadFile: logging reconfigured from /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings//logcontrol.xml
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2477) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Attempting to load settings for the group Global - from location Default
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2512) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Loaded settings file /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings/settings.xml
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2477) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Attempting to load settings for the group PerAccount - from location Default
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2512) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Loaded settings file /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings/settings_per_account.xml
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2477) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Attempting to load settings for the group CrashSettings - from location Default
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2512) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Loaded settings file /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings/settings_crash_behavior.xml
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2477) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Attempting to load settings for the group Warnings - from location Default
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2512) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Loaded settings file /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings/ignorable_dialogs.xml
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewerlinux.cpp(478) : initParseCommandLine: Language en
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewerlinux.cpp(479) : initParseCommandLine: Location US
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewerlinux.cpp(480) : initParseCommandLine: Variant UTF-8
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2693) : initConfiguration: Using command line specified settings filename: /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/settings_firestorm-release_v4.xml
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2477) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Attempting to load settings for the group Global - from location User
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2512) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Loaded settings file /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/settings_firestorm-release_v4.xml
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2477) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Attempting to load settings for the group CrashSettings - from location User
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z WARNING: llxml/llcontrol.cpp(939) : LLControlGroup::loadFromFile: Cannot find file /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings//home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/settings_crash_behavior.xml to load.
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2526) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Cannot load /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings//home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/settings_crash_behavior.xml - No settings found.
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2477) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Attempting to load settings for the group Warnings - from location User
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z WARNING: llxml/llcontrol.cpp(939) : LLControlGroup::loadFromFile: Cannot find file /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/ignorable_dialogs.xml to load.
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2526) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Cannot load /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/ignorable_dialogs.xml - No settings found.
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2477) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Attempting to load settings for the group Global - from location Session
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2512) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Loaded settings file /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings/settings_firestorm.xml
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2477) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Attempting to load settings for the group PerAccount - from location UserSession
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z WARNING: llxml/llcontrol.cpp(939) : LLControlGroup::loadFromFile: Cannot find file /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings/account_settings_firestorm.xml to load.
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2526) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Cannot load /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings/account_settings_firestorm.xml - No settings found.
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2477) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Attempting to load settings for the group Global - from location User
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2512) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Loaded settings file /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/settings_firestorm-release_v4.xml
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2477) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Attempting to load settings for the group CrashSettings - from location User
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z WARNING: llxml/llcontrol.cpp(939) : LLControlGroup::loadFromFile: Cannot find file /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings//home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/settings_crash_behavior.xml to load.
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2526) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Cannot load /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings//home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/settings_crash_behavior.xml - No settings found.
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2477) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Attempting to load settings for the group Warnings - from location User
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z WARNING: llxml/llcontrol.cpp(939) : LLControlGroup::loadFromFile: Cannot find file /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/ignorable_dialogs.xml to load.
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(2526) : loadSettingsFromDirectory: Cannot load /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/ignorable_dialogs.xml - No settings found.
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llviewernetwork.cpp(211) : initialize: Using last grid: util.agni.lindenlab.com
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llviewernetwork.cpp(397) : setGridChoice: setting util.agni.lindenlab.com
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(3909) : initMarkerFile: Exec marker found: program froze on previous execution
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(3400) : checkForCrash: Last execution froze, sending a crash report.
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: llcommon/llapp.cpp(664) : fork: Forked child process 6325
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: llcommon/llerror.cpp(334) : (anonymous namespace)::LogControlFile::loadFile: logging reconfigured from /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings//logcontrol.xml
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z INFO: llcrashlogger/llcrashlogger.cpp(583) : init: Loading crash behavior setting
2013-06-02T00:01:51Z WARNING: llxml/llcontrol.cpp(939) : LLControlGroup::loadFromFile: Cannot find file /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/settings_crash_behavior.xml to load.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: linux_crash_logger/linux_crash_logger.cpp(45) : main: Crash reporter finished normally.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llcommon/llapr.cpp(73) : ll_cleanup_apr: Cleaning up APR
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z WARNING: llui/lluicolortable.cpp(388) : LLUIColorTable::loadFromFilename: Unable to parse color file /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/colors.xml
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(850) : init: Configuration initialized.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(885) : init: LLCurl initialized.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(905) : init: Threads initialized.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(919) : init: UI initialized.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llui/llnotifications.cpp(1439) : LLNotifications::loadTemplates: Reading notifications template
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llui/llnotifications.cpp(1510) : LLNotifications::loadTemplates: ...done
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(934) : init: Notifications initialized.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(3643) : writeSystemInfo: Firestorm version 4.4.0
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(3651) : writeSystemInfo: Local time: 2013-06-02T03:01:52 EEST
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(3654) : writeSystemInfo: CPU info:
processor   : 0 
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel 
cpu family  : 6 
model       : 58 
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz 
stepping    : 9 
microcode   : 0x15 
cpu MHz     : 2000.000 
cache size  : 4096 KB 
physical id : 0 
siblings    : 4 
core id     : 0 
cpu cores   : 2 
apicid      : 0 
initial apicid  : 0 
fpu     : yes 
fpu_exception   : yes 
cpuid level : 13 
wp      : yes 
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64  
onitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms 
bogomips    : 4988.70 
clflush size    : 64 
cache_alignment : 64 
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual 
power management: 

processor   : 1 
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel 
cpu family  : 6 
model       : 58 
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz 
stepping    : 9 
microcode   : 0x15 
cpu MHz     : 775.000 
cache size  : 4096 KB 
physical id : 0 
siblings    : 4 
core id     : 0 
cpu cores   : 2 
apicid      : 1 
initial apicid  : 1 
fpu     : yes 
fpu_exception   : yes 
cpuid level : 13 
wp      : yes 
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64  
onitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms 
bogomips    : 4988.70 
clflush size    : 64 
cache_alignment : 64 
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual 
power management: 

processor   : 2 
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel 
cpu family  : 6 
model       : 58 
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz 
stepping    : 9 
microcode   : 0x15 
cpu MHz     : 2000.000 
cache size  : 4096 KB 
physical id : 0 
siblings    : 4 
core id     : 1 
cpu cores   : 2 
apicid      : 2 
initial apicid  : 2 
fpu     : yes 
fpu_exception   : yes 
cpuid level : 13 
wp      : yes 
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64  
onitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms 
bogomips    : 4988.70 
clflush size    : 64 
cache_alignment : 64 
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual 
power management: 

processor   : 3 
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel 
cpu family  : 6 
model       : 58 
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz 
stepping    : 9 
microcode   : 0x15 
cpu MHz     : 2000.000 
cache size  : 4096 KB 
physical id : 0 
siblings    : 4 
core id     : 1 
cpu cores   : 2 
apicid      : 3 
initial apicid  : 3 
fpu     : yes 
fpu_exception   : yes 
cpuid level : 13 
wp      : yes 
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64  
onitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms 
bogomips    : 4988.70 
clflush size    : 64 
cache_alignment : 64 
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual 
power management: 


->mHasSSE:     1
->mHasSSE2:    1
->mHasAltivec: 0
->mCPUMHz:     775
->mCPUString:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz (775 MHz)

2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(3655) : writeSystemInfo: Memory info:
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>            Active:      1236688
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>      Active(anon):       851732
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>      Active(file):       384956
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>     AnonHugePages:            0
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>         AnonPages:       850604
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>            Bounce:            0
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>           Buffers:        56300
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>            Cached:      1377984
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>       CommitLimit:      5974820
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>      Committed_AS:      3455840
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>       DirectMap2M:      8218624
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>       DirectMap4k:        77824
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>             Dirty:          120
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem> HardwareCorrupted:            0
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>    HugePages_Free:            0
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>    HugePages_Rsvd:            0
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>    HugePages_Surp:            0
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>   HugePages_Total:            0
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>      Hugepagesize:         2048
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>          Inactive:      1048316
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>    Inactive(anon):       173972
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>    Inactive(file):       874344
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>       KernelStack:         3528
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>            Mapped:       198772
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>           MemFree:      5490356
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>          MemTotal:      8044116
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>           Mlocked:           44
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>      NFS_Unstable:            0
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>        PageTables:        33116
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>      SReclaimable:        96436
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>        SUnreclaim:        29248
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>             Shmem:       174988
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>              Slab:       125684
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>        SwapCached:            0
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>          SwapFree:      1952764
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>         SwapTotal:      1952764
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>       Unevictable:           44
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>       VmallocUsed:       834388
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>         Writeback:            0
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>      WritebackTmp:            0
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z <mem>         timestamp: 2013-06-02T00:01:51.11Z
total pages: 1 unused pages: 1 total bytes: 1.00 used: 0.00 (0.00%) unused: 1.00
page usage (page #/% free): 0/100.0
small allocations (size/#/%): t/s (% s) 0/0(-nan)
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(3656) : writeSystemInfo: OS: Linux 3.5
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(3657) : writeSystemInfo: OS info: Linux 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:13:26 UTC 2013 x86_64
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(3537) : writeDebugInfo: Opening debug file /home/deus/.firestorm/logs/debug_info.log
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(956) : init: J2C Engine is: KDU v7.1
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(957) : init: libcurl version is: libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/1.0.0d zlib/1.2.5 c-ares/1.7.1
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z WARNING: llxml/llcontrol.cpp(939) : LLControlGroup::loadFromFile: Cannot find file /home/deus/.firestorm/user_settings/settings_crash_behavior.xml to load.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(999) : init: UI initialization is done.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewerlinux_api_dbus.cpp(72) : grab_dbus_syms: Found DSO: libdbus-glib-1.so.2
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(1048) : init: Hardware test initialization done.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/lltexturecache.cpp(973) : initCache: Headers: 377119 Textures size: 1422 MB
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/lltexturecache.cpp(1586) : purgeTextures: TEXTURE CACHE: Purging.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(4346) : initCache: VFS CACHE SIZE: 409 MB
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llvfs/llvfs.cpp(251) : LLVFS: Attempting to open VFS index file /home/deus/.firestorm/cache/index.db2.x.1
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llvfs/llvfs.cpp(252) : LLVFS: Attempting to open VFS data file /home/deus/.firestorm/cache/data.db2.x.1
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llvfs/llvfs.cpp(555) : LLVFS: Using VFS index file /home/deus/.firestorm/cache/index.db2.x.1
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llvfs/llvfs.cpp(556) : LLVFS: Using VFS data file /home/deus/.firestorm/cache/data.db2.x.1
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llvfs/llvfs.cpp(251) : LLVFS: Attempting to open VFS index file /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings/static_index.db2
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llvfs/llvfs.cpp(252) : LLVFS: Attempting to open VFS data file /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings/static_data.db2
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llvfs/llvfs.cpp(555) : LLVFS: Using VFS index file /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings/static_index.db2
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llvfs/llvfs.cpp(556) : LLVFS: Using VFS data file /home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/app_settings/static_data.db2
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(1069) : init: Cache initialization is done.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: newview/llappviewer.cpp(3424) : initWindow: Initializing window...
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llwindow/llwindowsdl.cpp(114) : ll_try_gtk_init: Starting GTK Initialization.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llwindow/llwindowsdl.cpp(134) : ll_try_gtk_init: GTK Initialized.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llwindow/llwindowsdl.cpp(135) : ll_try_gtk_init: - Compiled against GTK version 2.4.14
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llwindow/llwindowsdl.cpp(139) : ll_try_gtk_init: - Running against GTK version 2.24.10
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llwindow/llwindowsdl.cpp(155) : ll_try_gtk_init: - GTK version is good.
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llwindow/llwindowsdl.cpp(426) : createContext: createContext, fullscreen=0 size=1024x738
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llwindow/llwindowsdl.cpp(442) : createContext: Compiled against SDL 1.2.14
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llwindow/llwindowsdl.cpp(448) : createContext:  Running against SDL 1.2.14
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llwindow/llwindowsdl.cpp(473) : createContext: Original aspect ratio was 1920:1080=1.78
2013-06-02T00:01:52Z INFO: llwindow/llwindowsdl.cpp(636) : createContext: createContext: creating window 1024x738x32
The program 'do-not-directly-run-firestorm-bin' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)'.
  (Details: serial 13 error_code 1 request_code 154 minor_code 19)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
*** Bad shutdown ($LL_RUN_ERR). ***
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
You are running the Firestorm Viewer on a x86_64 platform.  The
most common problems when launching the Viewer (particularly
'bin/do-not-directly-run-firestorm-bin: not found' and 'error while
loading shared libraries') may be solved by installing your Linux
distribution's 32-bit compatibility packages.
For example, on Ubuntu and other Debian-based Linuxes you might run:
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk ia32-libs-kde ia32-libs-sdl
deus@work:~/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.0.33720$
```

Comment: [This post on the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1776491) is from 2011, but might still help you out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [64bit Ubuntu 14.04, running 32bit binaries](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/64bit-ubuntu-14-04-running-32bit-binaries)

Answer (score -1):

http://wiki.phoenixviewer.com/32-bit_firestorm_in_64-bit_ubuntu

If you take all steps here it should fix your problem, however be careful about things being removed, depending on your exact ubuntu version. Especially if your working on something later than 14.04 avoid the growl notification bit as it uninstalls some huge sections of the o/s. Do eac